# Oracle aggregate specific groups based on sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table T:

```
Entity  type  starttime    sequence  duration
1       A     2017010101   1         12
1       A     2017010102   2         11
1       A     2017010103   3         3
1       A     2017010104   4         1
1       A     2017010105   1         19
1       A     2017010106   2         18
2       A     2017010101   1         18
2       A     2017010102   1         100
3       A     2017010101   1         120
```

I need to aggregate the data so that each run of sequence has a total duration and the first starttime:

```
Entity  type  starttime    sequence  duration
1       A     2017010101   1         27
1       A     2017010105   1         37
2       A     2017010101   1         18
2       A     2017010102   1         100
3       A     2017010101   1         120
```

I believe this is a gaps-and-islands problem, but I can't quite figure it out...

I have tried to use a `lead() over (partition by entity order by sequence)` but this keeps grabbing the next run of sequence.

Comment: Don't have an oracle connection to hand to test the write of it, but a recursive CTE / Connect By (depending on Oracle version, 11gr1 / r2), select the rows with sequence = 1, grouped by entity as the anchor and then recurse based on sequence = sequence + 1 and date = date +1 summing the values as you go along. In your data above I think the line 2       A     2017010102   1         100 is meant to be 2       A     2017010102   2         100

Comment: @Andrew That line was wrong, but for another reason... Edit made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `sequence` has no gaps then you can use `row_number()` and subtract sequence to create temporary column `grp` used next for aggregation:

```
select entity, type, min(starttime) starttime, 
       min(sequence) sequence, sum(duration) duration
  from (select t.*, 
               row_number() over (partition by entity order by starttime) - sequence grp 
          from t)
  group by entity, type, grp
  order by entity, grp
```

Test:

```
with t(entity, type, starttime, sequence, duration) as (
    select 1, 'A', 2017010101, 1,  12 from dual union all
    select 1, 'A', 2017010102, 2,  11 from dual union all
    select 1, 'A', 2017010103, 3,   3 from dual union all
    select 1, 'A', 2017010104, 4,   1 from dual union all
    select 1, 'A', 2017010105, 1,  19 from dual union all
    select 1, 'A', 2017010106, 2,  18 from dual union all
    select 2, 'A', 2017010101, 1,  18 from dual union all
    select 2, 'A', 2017010102, 1, 100 from dual union all
    select 3, 'A', 2017010101, 1, 120 from dual )
select entity, type, min(starttime) starttime, 
       min(sequence) sequence, sum(duration) duration
  from (select t.*, 
               row_number() over (partition by entity order by starttime) - sequence grp 
          from t)
  group by entity, type, grp
  order by entity, grp



    ENTITY TYPE  STARTTIME   SEQUENCE   DURATION
---------- ---- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 A    2017010101          1         27
         1 A    2017010105          1         37
         2 A    2017010101          1         18
         2 A    2017010102          1        100
         3 A    2017010101          1        120
```

Comment: This is more elegant than the CTE I was constructing

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `row_number()` for this.  You can just subtract the sequence from the `starttime` -- assuming `starttime` is a date.  The difference is constant for each group of sequential values:

```
select entity, type, min(starttime) as starttime, 
       min(sequence) as sequence, sum(duration) as duration
from t
group by entity, type, (starttime - sequence)
order by entity, grp;
```

If `starttime` is a string then you need `row_number()` as Ponder suggests.  If `starttime` is a number, then this works within a single month, but you probably want `row_number()`.